# Parent DIV resize vertically when top property is used on inner DIV

Tags: html, css

I have quite simply example where outer DIV is not completely resized according to content. Problem is top property of inner DIV, which makes it slip out of parent. Is there a way to resize outer DIV vertically, no matter if top property is used? I know I can use jQuery for this, but is it possible to do with CSS only?

```html
<div id="divPTX_01" style="position:relative;min-height:1px;overflow:hidden;min-width:1px; border: 1px solid red;">             
    <div style="position:relative;float:left;border:2px solid blue;top:130px;">
      <span>Test</span><br/>
      <span>Test</span><br/>
      <span>Test</span><br/>
      
      
      <span>Test 6</span><br/>
      <span>Test 7</span><br/>
      <span>Test</span><br/>
      <span>Test</span><br/>
      <span>Test</span><br/>
      
      
      <span>Test 6</span><br/>
      <span>Test 7</span><br/>
    </div>
      
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not clear on what it is you are trying to do. Why should the outer div resize?

Comment: BEcause inner div slips out of parent. I want parent to resize with child even if top property is used on child div.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

instead of top try using margin-top

```html
<div id="divPTX_01" style="position:relative;min-height:1px;overflow:hidden;min-width:1px; border: 1px solid red;">             
    <div style="position:relative;float:left;border:2px solid blue;margin-top:130px">
      <span>Test</span><br/>
      <span>Test</span><br/>
      <span>Test</span><br/>
      
      
      <span>Test 6</span><br/>
      <span>Test 7</span><br/>
      <span>Test</span><br/>
      <span>Test</span><br/>
      <span>Test</span><br/>
      
      
      <span>Test 6</span><br/>
      <span>Test 7</span><br/>
    </div>
      
</div>
```